# Sequelize validation doesn't work on PUT method

Tags: javascript, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I'm pretty new to Sequelize. Here's a model that I have. The validation seems to be working fine on POST method, but it doesn't work on PUT method. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'd appreciate all the help guys.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  class Course extends Sequelize.Model {}
  Course.init({
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notNull: {
          msg: 'Please provide a value for "title"'
        },
        notEmpty: {
          msg: 'Please provide a value for "title"'
        }
      }
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notNull: {
          msg: 'Please provide a value for "description"'
        },
        notEmpty: {
          msg: 'Please provide a value for "description"'
        }
      }
    }
  }, { sequelize });

  Course.associate = (models) => {
    Course.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: {
       fieldName: 'userId',
       allowNull: false
      }
    })
  };

  return Course
}
```

Here's my code on main route.

```
router.put('/courses/:id', asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const course = await Course.findByPk(req.params.id)
    await course.update(req.body);
    res.status(204).end();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}));
```